# Canvas Working Fine In All Browsers Except Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, drawimage

I hava JS script that takes an image and draws it to a canvas. The code works perfectly fine in all browsers except Chrome. I have included the relevant

```
    this.tile = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = this.tile.getContext("2d");

    this.tile.width = ((size.cm_size) * (((this.image.width) / this.app.dpi.active) * 2.54)).toFixed(2);
    this.tile.height = ((size.cm_size) * (((this.image.height) / this.app.dpi.active) * 2.54)).toFixed(2);

    if (this.scale > 0) {
        // These 2 lines break it in Chrome.
        this.tile.width = this.tile.width * this.scale;
        this.tile.height = this.tile.height * this.scale;
    }

    ctx.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.image.width, this.image.height, 0, 0, this.image.width, this.image.height);
```

I have commented the 2 lines that break things in Chrome. Removing these lines makes things work.

With these lines in place, nothing is displayed until I increase the 'this.app.dpi.active' variable to 350 (it starts at 150). As soon as this happens it displays how it does in Firefox.

There are no error messages, the tile is just empty.

Here's a list of values for 'this.app.dpi.active' and the resulting tile width and height. The tile doesn't display until the value DPI hits 350.

```
150 DPI = 9444 x 9444
200 DPI = 7084 x 7084
250 DPI = 5668 x 5668
300 DPI = 4720 x 4720
350 DPI = 4048 x 4048
```

I have checked these vales in Chrome and Firefox and they are identical but things work in Firefox. The this.scale value = 4 and when the width and height aren't multipled by this.scale, it works fine in FF and Chrome.

Please let me know if you need any more code or have any questions.

Comment: `new Element`? I don't think you can do that. You have to actually do `document.createElement`

Comment: Can you give some examples of what the variables might be? If those two lines are breaking the code then there's probably a math issue somewhere.

Comment: I've added the values. These are identical in FF and Chrome. I have also added a link to the page so you can try this out in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured this one out myself but thank you everyone for your input!

I noticed that once an image got to a certain size, Chrome display it correctly. This led me to believe that Chrome doesn't allow canvas elements over a certain size (probably for memory/efficiency reasons). To fix this I re-designed my system slightly so that canvas elements never get too big and therefore always displayed correctly. This fixed the issue in Chrome and made my system a fair bit quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the Element constructor.  I've always used `document.createElement('canvas')`.  In my FF console, using the Element constructor throws an error.

Comment: It throws an error on Chrome too. Perhaps OP has made his own `Element` constructor.

Comment: It's Prototype.js so new Element('canvas') should be the same as document.createElement('canvas'). That being said, I have modified the code to use your version but the error is exactly the same.